# If condition adding all items to array

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, arrays

I have a user list in my angular app and all I wanted to do is filter users with `if` condition, if user's `age > 45` push it into `validForScheme` array but it's pushing all users in array. I can't figureout what's going wrong.

Another thing is `ng-repeat` showing one extra blank item.

**Note:** I'm getting `$scope.allUsers` from database with `http` method.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.allUsers = [{"age": 54,"name": "Corrine Benson"},{"age": 38,"name": "Thompson Newton"},{"age": 62,"name": "Molly Good"},{"age": 66,"name": "Kristine Mcbride"},{"age": 45,"name": "Kathy Estrada"},{"age": 22,"name": "Krystal Davis"},{"age": 53,"name": "Butler Greene"},{"age": 34,"name": "Hogan Joseph"}];
$scope.validForScheme = [];

$scope.filterUsers = function(arg) {
 if (arg.age > 45)
   console.log(arg.name, 'is valid for Scheme');
   $scope.validForScheme.push(arg);
}

$scope.allUsers.forEach(function(item, index){
  $scope.filterUsers(item);
})
console.log($scope.validForScheme);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <ol>
    <li ng-repeat="users in validForScheme">{{users.name}}, {{users.age}}<li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: `$scope.validForScheme.push(arg);` should be `$scope.validForScheme.push(arg.name);`

Comment: @BlueSuiter I want to push whole `arg` not just `arg.name`

Comment: @BlueSuiter , no I think he just want to filter the complete array while keeping required object (that is age greater than 45)

Comment: @AbhishekPandey the console you have used is showing desired output?

Comment: silly you make the parenthesis omit after if condition, and your console.log is being counted as conditional statement and `.push` pushing all, silly mistake

Comment: Your code would work fine if you add proper `{}` after `if`. This has been highlighted in one of the answer.

Comment: There was tons of code in script file therefore somehow I skipped this. thanks for help, and many thanks to Downvoter to downvote. :)

Comment: @Rajesh I got your point about enclose, but why `ng-repeat` is showing an extra blank item?

Comment: @AbhishekPandey Shouldn't `ng-repeat` be on `ol`?

Comment: I want to repeat `list item` not `list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to enclose the contents of `if` statement within braces `{}`.

When not enclosed within a braces, `if` considers only one(immediate) line/statement as its scope.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.allUsers = [{
    "age": 54,
    "name": "Corrine Benson"
  }, {
    "age": 38,
    "name": "Thompson Newton"
  }, {
    "age": 62,
    "name": "Molly Good"
  }, {
    "age": 66,
    "name": "Kristine Mcbride"
  }, {
    "age": 45,
    "name": "Kathy Estrada"
  }, {
    "age": 22,
    "name": "Krystal Davis"
  }, {
    "age": 53,
    "name": "Butler Greene"
  }, {
    "age": 34,
    "name": "Hogan Joseph"
  }];

  $scope.validForScheme = [];

  $scope.filterUsers = function(arg) {
    if (arg.age > 45) {
      console.log(arg.name, 'is valid for Scheme');
      $scope.validForScheme.push(arg);
    }
  }

  $scope.allUsers.forEach(function(item, index) {
    $scope.filterUsers(item);
  })
  console.log($scope.validForScheme);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <ol>
    <li ng-repeat="users in validForScheme">{{users.name}}, {{users.age}}
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: @Rajesh : OP's issue is with `if` statement and not filtering.

Comment: @Pugazh This question could still be closed as a duplicate, then.

Comment: I missed that completely. Now this makes it a typo error. But still in my understanding, answers should not be there on the post

Comment: @Pugazh I got your point about enclose, but why `ng-repeat` is showing an extra blank item?

Comment: @AbhishekPandey : It's just a typo error, you missed the closing tag `/`. i.e `{{users.age}}<li>` should be `{{users.age}}</li>`

Comment: Ohh, I guess this is my typo error day :D, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `Array.filter` directly instead. Like this:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.allUsers = [{"age": 54,"name": "Corrine Benson"},{"age": 38,"name": "Thompson Newton"},{"age": 62,"name": "Molly Good"},{"age": 66,"name": "Kristine Mcbride"},{"age": 45,"name": "Kathy Estrada"},{"age": 22,"name": "Krystal Davis"},{"age": 53,"name": "Butler Greene"},{"age": 34,"name": "Hogan Joseph"}];

$scope.validForScheme = $scope.allUsers.filter(function(item, index){
  return item.age > 45
})
console.log($scope.validForScheme);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <ol>
    <li ng-repeat="users in validForScheme">{{users.name}}, {{users.age}}</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: But why `ng-repeat` is showing an extra blank item?

Comment: @AbhishekPandey your `li` tag doesn't get completed

Answer (score 2):

You need to enclose multiple statement in `if` with `{}`.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.allUsers = [{"age": 54,"name": "Corrine Benson"},{"age": 38,"name": "Thompson Newton"},{"age": 62,"name": "Molly Good"},{"age": 66,"name": "Kristine Mcbride"},{"age": 45,"name": "Kathy Estrada"},{"age": 22,"name": "Krystal Davis"},{"age": 53,"name": "Butler Greene"},{"age": 34,"name": "Hogan Joseph"}];
$scope.validForScheme = [];

$scope.filterUsers = function(arg) {
 if (arg.age > 45){
     //console.log(arg.name, 'is valid for Scheme');
     $scope.validForScheme.push(arg);
   }
}

$scope.allUsers.forEach(function(item, index){
  //console.log(item)
  $scope.filterUsers(item);
})
//console.log($scope.validForScheme);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <ol>
    <li ng-repeat="users in validForScheme">{{users.name}}, {{users.age}}</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Alright, that's solved the problem, but `console.log(arg.name, 'is valid for Scheme');` is working without enclosing statement, WHY?

Comment: If you do not add `{}` after `if` it considers only next line as in its scope

Comment: @AbhishekPandey haha, that's because first statement after an `if` is considered inside it :)

Comment: @tanmay Though it correct answer, I'd request you to not answer such typographical mistakes

Comment: There was tons of code in script file therefore somehow I skipped this. thanks for help.

Comment: @Mamun What about 5th blank item it `ng-repeat`?

Comment: @Abhishek Pandey, I was looking at the extra blank element as well. Didn't make any significant change, still the problem disappears.

Answer (score 1):

If statement missing the brackets

```
        $scope.filterUsers = function (arg) {
            if (arg.age > 45) {
                console.log(arg.name, 'is valid for Scheme');
                $scope.validForScheme.push(arg);
            }
        }
```

Working code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>


<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <ol>
            <li ng-repeat="users in validForScheme">{{users.name}}, {{users.age}}
                <li>
        </ol>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

        app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {

            $scope.allUsers = [{
                "age": 54,
                "name": "Corrine Benson"
            }, {
                "age": 38,
                "name": "Thompson Newton"
            }, {
                "age": 62,
                "name": "Molly Good"
            }, {
                "age": 66,
                "name": "Kristine Mcbride"
            }, {
                "age": 45,
                "name": "Kathy Estrada"
            }, {
                "age": 22,
                "name": "Krystal Davis"
            }, {
                "age": 53,
                "name": "Butler Greene"
            }, {
                "age": 34,
                "name": "Hogan Joseph"
            }];
            $scope.validForScheme = [];

            $scope.filterUsers = function (arg) {
                if (arg.age > 45) {
                    console.log(arg.name, 'is valid for Scheme');
                    $scope.validForScheme.push(arg);
                }
            }

            $scope.allUsers.forEach(function (item, index) {
                $scope.filterUsers(item);
            })
            console.log($scope.validForScheme);

        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I got your point about enclose, but why `ng-repeat` is showing an extra blank item?

Answer (score 0):

`validForScheme = allUsers.filter(user => user.age > 45)`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 0):

For a simpler, cleaner and reliable implementation, use just array filter:

```
$scope.allUsers = [{"age": 54,"name": "Corrine Benson"},{"age": 38,"name": "Thompson Newton"},{"age": 62,"name": "Molly Good"},{"age": 66,"name": "Kristine Mcbride"},{"age": 45,"name": "Kathy Estrada"},{"age": 22,"name": "Krystal Davis"},{"age": 53,"name": "Butler Greene"},{"age": 34,"name": "Hogan Joseph"}];

$scope.validForScheme = $scope.allUsers.filter(user => user.age > 45);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the parenthesis after if condition, and that's why immediate console.log is being counted as conditional statement not your `$scope.validForScheme.push(arg);`